# How to return all nodes which have at least X pathes over Y hops

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am new to neo4j, so maybe this is a very easy question...
Lets take an example with X=2, Y=2

DB:

```
CREATE (a:Node{name:'A'})
CREATE (b:Node{name:'B'})
CREATE (c:Node{name:'C'})

CREATE (c1:Category{name:'c1'})
CREATE (c2:Category{name:'c2'})

CREATE (a)-[:REL]->(c1)<-[:REL]-(b)
CREATE (a)-[:REL]->(c2)<-[:REL]-(b)
CREATE (c)-[:REL]->(c2)
```

[image]

If startpoint is A, query should return following since only B is connected over 2 paths with a max number of hops=2.

[image]

Without the constraint of 2 path I could use following, but this would also show the C node:

```
MATCH (start:Node {name:"A"})-[*1..2]-(res) 
RETURN start, res
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for this one, you will need to use count() to get the number of times the end node is reached (the number of different paths to that node), then filter based upon that count:

```
MATCH (start:Node {name:"A"})-[*2]-(res)  // or [*..2] if up to 2 instead of exactly 2
WITH start, res, count(res) as paths
WHERE paths >= $requiredPaths // assumes a `requiredPaths` parameter to the query
RETURN start, res
```

Comment: Since the question states an exact number of hops (i.e., "2", not "up to 2"), the relationship pattern should probably be `[*2]` instead of `[*..2]`.

Comment: Good catch, wasn't quite sure what was really needed here. Changed accordingly.